# Calculated field always returns 1 - atk 4.2

Tags: atk4

I have a model that has a calculated field. The value returned is always 1. After turning the debug on, 1 is hardcoded in the query:

```
<?php class Model_Income extends Model_base_Income {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->debug();
        $this->addField('year')->calculated(true);
    }
    function calculate_year(){
        return '22';
    }
}
```

Query returned by debug

```
    select `name`
,(select `name` from `client` where `income`.`client_id` = `client`.`id` )
`client`,`amount`,`date`,`comment`,1 `year`,`id` 
    from `income`
```

I am using atk 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 4.2 do so:

in model.

```
$this->add("Field_Expression", "year")->set("22");
```

or any sql query instead of 22.

Comment: actually it's $this->addExpression('year')->set('22'); but that is simply a shortcut.

Comment: add("Field_XXX", $field_name) is fine, as we have more fancy Field types such as "filestore/Field_File" etc.

Comment: Thanks romaninsh, when you say more, do you have a list or something? I have looked here [link](http://agiletoolkit.org/dox/html/) but couldn't see others, beside expression and reference.

Comment: Yes, here is documentation link: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/modeltable/expression