# Agile Toolkit addExpression and DSQL

Tags: frameworks, atk4, php

I have been following the book provided by the agile toolkit and am at this portion:
http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/logic

Unfortunately the dsql api lacks some clarity and the calculated fields example on that page is just not working.

I tried using:

```
class Model_DVD extends Model_Table {

        public $table='dvd';

    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Movie');
        $this->addField('code');
        $this->addfield('is_rented')
            ->type('boolean')
            ->calculated(true);
    }

    function calculate_is_rented(){
        return $this->add('Model_Rental')
            ->dsql()
            ->field('id')
            ->where('rental.dvd_id=dvd.id')
            ->where('is_returned!=','Y')
            ->select()
            ;
    }
}
```

This returns 1 every time so I tried to follow:
[Calculated field always returns 1 - atk 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286262/calculated-field-always-returns-1-atk-4-2)

And now I'm not sure how to create this properly; I know the following works but I kind of made it up as I went and have NO IDEA why it works, and why I need the count() - etc etc.

How do I go about getting the calculated field to work? Can someone please explain it in this example, I learn best by examples so I wanted to follow through with it.

My working code that I don't understand:

```
class Model_DVD extends Model_Table {

    public $table='dvd';

    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Movie');
        $this->addField('code');

        $this->debug();

        $this->addExpression('is_rented')->set($this->add('Model_Rental')
                                                    ->addCondition('dvd_id', $this->_dsql()->getField('id'))
                                                    ->count()
                                                    ->where('is_returned!=','Y'))
                                                    ->datatype('boolean')
                                                    ->enum(array('Y', 'N'));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSQL APP tutorial is for Agile Toolkit 4.1.

Please watch the screencasts http://youtube.com/theagiletoolkit for updated and more extensive tutorial.